# jQuery cssHooks is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hook css get/set. However after installing a simple pass thru hook it seems to be not called: (no error messages in Chrome console)

```
    $.cssHooks['padding-left'] = {
        get: function( elem, computed, extra ) {
            return $.css( elem, $['padding-left'] );
        },
        set: function( elem, value) {
            // Setting breakpoint here in Chrome, this line is not called:
            elem.style[ $.support['padding-left'] ] = value;
        }
    };
    // Proof of concept: Should not this statement initiate the hooked setter call?
    // This statement is called, confirmed via breakpoint
    $('#et-top-navigation').css('padding-left', '0px');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `$.cssHooks.paddingLeft = {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the camel-case javascript property name rather than the hyphenated css style.

```
$.cssHooks['paddingLeft'] = { ...
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is called.

Answer (score -1):

You need wrap all of that in a document ready call, because jQuery writes cssHooks at this time and will get rid of your functions if they exist.

Take a look at the skeleton template in the API
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/

```
(function( $ ) {

    // First, check to see if cssHooks are supported
    if ( !$.cssHooks ) {
      // If not, output an error message
      throw( new Error( "jQuery 1.4.3 or above is required for this plugin to work" ) );
    }

    // Wrap in a document ready call, because jQuery writes
    // cssHooks at this time and will blow away your functions
    // if they exist.
    $(function () {
      $.cssHooks[ "someCSSProp" ] = {
        get: function( elem, computed, extra ) {
          // Handle getting the CSS property
        },
        set: function( elem, value ) {
          // Handle setting the CSS value
        }
      };
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: @g.pickardou How is that of course? Where did you show/tell us that it was? Based on a first glance it wasn't wrapped

Comment: @g.pickardou figured that, but still a possibility. Could help someone else, as it is general cssHooks knowledge, figured I'd put it up in case.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway, however it would be more appropriate to drop a comment line instead, something similar like: "do you call it in the document ready?"